# EditText cannot be edited after setting enabled back to true

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an `EditText pageTitle`, and it should only be editable if my `RelativeLayout addPhotoLayout` is not visible. This is my code:

```
if(addPhotoLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
    pageTitle.setEnabled(false);
} else {
    pageTitle.setEnabled(true);
}
```

The problem is even when `addPhotoLayout` is gone or no longer visible, `pageTitle` won't revert to its editable status. I did try changing the values of `focusable` and `focusableInTouchMode`, but the same issue persists.

Comment: Try setEditable  to true and setFocusableInTouchMode to true and then try again

Comment: Please never post ephemeral content like paste.ofcode.org on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the state of `pageTitle` when you update the visibility of `addPhotoLayout`.
In your `setMomentPicture` method, you are setting the visibility of `addPhotoLayout` to `GONE`, but `pageTitle` does not get notified of this.

You could implement a method like this:

```
private method setAddPhotoLayoutVisible(boolean setVisible) {
  if(setVisible) {
    addPhotoLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    pageTitle.setEnabled(false);
  } else {
    addPhotoLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    pageTitle.setEnabled(true);
  }
}
```

And call it when you need to update the visibility of `addPhotoLayout`.